# Problems writing to text file

Tags: python, file, text

I'm having a little trouble writing data to text files with python. Basically, what I want to do is read information in a text file, update the read text, and write the updated information back to the same text file. Reading and updating the text is easy enough, however, I run into difficulties when I try to write the updated text back to the text file.

The text file is very basic and consists of three lines. Here it is:

```
48850

z_merged_shapefiles

EDRN_048850
```

I used the code below to try and update it but got this error: `'file' object has no attribute 'writeline'`

Here is the code that I used:

```
fo = open("C:\\Users\\T0015685\\Documents\\Python\\Foo1.txt", "r")

read1 = fo.readline()
read2 = fo.readline()
read3 = fo.readline()

fo.close()

edrn_v = int(read1) + 1
newID = "EDRN_" + str(edrn_v)

fo = open("C:\\Users\\T0015685\\Documents\\Python\\Foo1.txt", "w")

fo.writeline(edrn_v)
fo.writeline(read2)
fo.writeline(newID)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although there is a `readline` there is no analog `writeline`.

You can either use a `write` and append a `'\n'` to terminate a line

```
with open("C:\\Users\\T0015685\\Documents\\Python\\Foo1.txt", "w") as fo:
    fo.write(edrn_v + '\n')
    fo.write(read2 + '\n')
    fo.write(newID + '\n')
```

Or put all the variables in a `list` and use `writelines`.

```
with open("C:\\Users\\T0015685\\Documents\\Python\\Foo1.txt", "w") as fo:
    fo.writelines([edrn_v, read2, newID])
```

**Note**

I am using the [with open](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement

```
with open() as f:
```

So you don't have to manage the `open` and `close` yourself

```
f.open()
f.read()
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Cyber, your answer works. One problem though, it does read and write as I would expect but creates a space on line 3 and moves the content I would expect to be there to line 4. Do you know why this happens and how I can stop it?